# Set and Get Cookie locally in Python 3, Tkinter

Tags: python, cookies, python-3.x, tkinter, setcookie

I've searching all over for a way to set a cookie locally, in Python 3, via a Tkinter GUI, and only get httplib2 results, which don't work.

Essentially I have a simple login UI, which will make a SimpleCookie:

```
def signIn(self):
    user = self.login_var.get()
    passwd = self.password_var.get()
    C = cookies.SimpleCookie()
    C['user'] = user
    C['passwd'] = passwd
    print(C.output(attrs=[], header='Cookie:'))
    self.confirm()
```

...but then I can't retrieve/pass the cookie to the next command:

```
def confirm(self):
    self.top = Toplevel()
    self.top.title('Congrats!')
    self.top_frame = Frame(self.top)
    self.top_frame.grid()
    self.lbl = Label(self.top_frame, text='Hello ' + C['user'].value + '!')
    self.lbl.grid()
```

I'm sure I'm missing something (lots of things?) since I'm super new to Python >.<

Answer (score 1):

You can add a parameter to confirm like this

```
def confirm(self, C)
```

then call it with

```
self.confirm(C)
```

In python a variable can be any object, literal (int, byte etc) or function even.

Additionally you can change the variable C to a class-wide variable which is using

```
self.C = cookies.SimpleCookie() # Prefixing self. attributes with an underscore _ is  commonly
                                # used to declare a soft private variable. 
                                # Other classes and modules can still access it but it generally 
                                # means it is not supposed to be accessed from outside the class.
```

Now you can address C from within the class by:

```
self.C
```

and from outside the class by:

```
ClassName.C
```

Comment: they could also change `C` to `self.C`. You might want to add that additional solution to your answer.

Comment: Thanks added a small explanation.